# Selenium not able to identify the newly opened window in the IE browser

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, internet-explorer-9

I am not able to identify a newly opened window in my application.

After using driver.get("my app url") when I try to click on any object, I am getting  org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find element on closed window.
I replicated the same issue on flipkart website using the below code :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","path to IEDriverServer.exe);    

WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();          

driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com");

Thread.sleep(10000); // just for sample 

driver.findElement(By.linkText("24x7 Customer Care")).click();
```

But when I run it I am getting NoSuchWindowException.
It is working fine in chrome and Firefox browser.

Selenium Version =2.53.0 ,
OS= Windows7

I tried by adding ignoreProtectedMode and IntroduceFlakinessByIgnoringSecurityDomains capabilities as well but even that is working.

Kindly assist.

Comment: Does `IE` browser session actually opens?

Comment: yes do u see any IE window get opened by selenium

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "path to IEdriverServer.exe" );
    WebDriver driver =new InternetExplorerDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com");
  do {
   System.out.println("window size" +driver.getWindowHandles().size());
  }while(driver.getWindowHandles().size()!=0);
  System.out.println("Window size after loop ends " +driver.getWindowHandles().size());                Output is :window size1
window size0
Window size after loop ends 0

Comment: Seems like window gets opened and then it is closed automatically...

Comment: can you do a fresh installation of your IE,may be that helps

Comment: I already re installed IE.. I checked in both IE 9 and IE 11 . It is not working.   This issue is happening for almost all the websites. I tried on google.com as well

Answer (score 0):

Use this it works for you

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "path to IEdriverServer.exe" ); 
WebDriver driver =new InternetExplorerDriver(); 
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com");
```

Comment: Download latest IEDriver